# The C# this[] bracket constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I found in another library that you can call class instances using all sorts of parameters...

They used a `this[int y, int z]` format.

I tried to replicate it, but I can't find anything in any C# website.

```
class xx
    {
        private int _y { get; private set; }
        private int _z { get; private set; }
        public xx this[int y, int z] { get; set; }
        public xx(int y, int z){
            _y = y;
            _z = z;
        }
    }


    xx z = new xx(1, 2);
    xx y = xx[1, 2];
```

I'm trying to figure out, how to use this `this[options]` format. **(The above code is totally wrong)**

It would make things easier to not have to establish new instances each time.

Instead of going:

```
Column y = new Column(1, "value", "attributes;attribute;attribute");
FullTable.Add(y);
```

I could do:

```
FullTable.Column[1, "value", "attributes;attribute;attribute"]; // can get the instance or create it.
```

and it would already be instantiated and everything.

Anyway how would an OOP guru do this? Any ideas at all please?

Comment: It's not a constructor, it's an indexer.  You need to implement the getter and the setter.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: I understand but how would you make it a constructor as well like I was thinking of? Using Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); ??

Comment: Construct the object in the indexer?

Comment: Use http://www.SymbolHound.com for searching language related stuff, see [the results](http://symbolhound.com/?q=this%5B%5D+c%23)

Comment: @Habib, cool, very nice reference to know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an indexer and is used to reference an item in your class.

For example, suppose you wanted to write a program that organized your DVD movie collection. You could have a constructor for creating DVD movies to put into the collection, but it would be useful to "get" a DVD movie by an ID, which an indexer would allow for.

```
public class MovieCollection
{
    private Dictionary<string, Movie> movies = 
               new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
    private Dictionary<int, string> moviesById = 
               new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public MovieCollection()
    {

    }

    // Indexer to get movie by ID
    public Movie this[int index]  
    {
        string title = moviesById[index];
        return movies[title];
    }
}
```

Comment: @KirkWoll - I did say "almost", but I meant to say used in use cases where you are trying to reference an array of items, which to the caller they do not care how the data is stored internally, as shown by my code example. I am updating the answer to remove the "harsh" language. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `this[int x]` syntax is called an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). It's how you can implement the sort of thing used in arrays, lists, and dictionaries to let you do, e.g. `myList[0]`. It cannot be used as a constructor, you should just use the ordinary constructor syntax you already know for that.